# Python SMTP Verify email

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

```
import smtplib
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login("MY USER", "MY PASS")

    message = "Hi, recruit?"


    server.sendmail("FROME WHO", "TO WHOM", message)
    server.quit()
    print("email is valid")
except:
    print("email invalid")
```

***Goal***: I need to verify if the email I'm sending does exist. I would like the script to give me a traceback if the email doesn't exist.

***Problem***: The email get's sent even when the email doesn't exist, I get to receive email from google though saying that the email doesn't exist in my Gmail.

***steps taken***: I've tried the instance method SMTP.verify which would send me a status code of 404 if the email doesn't exist, but the email is getting sent even though it doesn't exist.

***Question:*** is there a setting in Gmail where I can change to say if an email doesn't exist, please give me an error. Or maybe there's a workaround on my script that I didn't know yet?

This is the code for verify and also the return
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTZJE.png

Comment: Can you show what code you use when you used `server.verify()`?

Comment: sure, updated the post.

Comment: Do you ever actually checl what `server.verify()` returns? Or do you just run it? It [returns a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.verify) that you should be checking, and the error code is not necessarily 404, but rather >400

Comment: according to the documentation of SMTP, 250+ if it's successful. 404 if not. 

in this one, I'm receiving 252 even though it's not a valid email where I expect to get a 404 because the email aiosdoureaw@gmail.com is not valid.

Comment: 252 means it's not a valid email, but the server will attempt to send the message anyway. Do a quick Google search for "smtp 252"

Comment: interesting, so I've tried it with a valid email however it's still the same. I'm not expecting it to be 252 with my valid email though. How do I differentiate it if it's a valid one or not?

Comment: SMTP VFY command asks server to verify if address exists on _this_ server. So if you connect smtp.gmail.com it can check the address served by gmail.
Code 252 means  that the server doesn't know whether the address is valid.

The reliable way to check if user@domain.com address exists is to connect to mail exchanger for that domain and check response to RCPT TO: comand.

Comment: yes, I do get that and it did cross into my possible solution. However, what if I'm dealing with a thousand emails. How do I automate this one? that's my purpose for doing this in python.